# why use a small learning rate in gradient descent

Tags: optimization, data-mining, descent

I am new to neural networks and recently found out about gradient descent.

Something does not sit right with me.

```
x←x−λ∇fk(x)
```

Why does this formula work? Wouldn't it make more sense to have lambda a large value thereby mimizing the cost function?

I am not phrasing my question properly as i am honestly quite confused. How could gradient descent result in a global optimum if it always reduces the value?

Comment: the lambda controls the descent, you can quickly become unstable and finding the solution will be difficult if not impossible. In a similar way that you have to be careful of step size when solving certain differential equations (namely some nonlinear ones)

Comment: If you are looking at minizing the function wouldn't it make sense to have infinity as lambda? And x - infinity would give u negative infinity?

Comment: You can adjust $\lambda$ using line search. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search

Comment: What I am confused about is a case when the loss function actually is not minimized when using a huge learning rate as opposed to a smaller one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain you clearly:

Learning rate is the length of the steps the algorithm makes down the gradient on the error curve.

So, in case you have a high learning rate, the algorithm might overshoot the optimal point.

And with a lower learning rate, in case of any overshoot, the magnitude of overshoot would be lesser than when you have a higher learning rate.

So, in case of overshoot, you would end up at a non-optimal point whose error would be higher.

Comment: Yes and why isit so? Can I have an example of such a case? Maybe some equations and numbers

Comment: You might want to have a watch at this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WGK1GrFYd8) of Professor Andrew Ng.  He did a great job in explaining the downside of having high learning rate.